# Unable to launch UI of java application which is executed by scheduler executed by system user

Tags: windows, python, batch-file, shell-script, windows-task-scheduler

I have a python script which runs via windows task scheduler, I have to launch a javaFx application jar from this python script, when I execute the python script from cmd it launches the jar, also it launches when the scheduler user is logged in user, but it does not work if the user of scheduler is system.
Below is the screenshot of scheduler configuration
[image]

Comment: Valid question, but please do not include a link to an external reference (might be volatile and not last as long as the question here on SuperUser). Can you edit the question here to make it fully self-containing?

Comment: Thank you @Edward for your feedback, as it was my first question, I was not allowed to post image because I didn't had 10 reputations, now I have uploaded the image